# What is the exact difference between the game and game engine?

Tags: terminology

I thought game engine are something like Unity or Unreal. They have a editor with scene editor, some Physics library, some scripting editor and tools to improve the workflow of developer. Furthermore, I thought game engine should independent of the actually game.(i.e.) The game engine should not have any game logic in it.

However, I watched this game engine video and I am totally confused. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK7ntA7a2vk . In the game engine video, I don't see the game engine anywhere because it seemed as though the professor developed the game straightaway.

I hope someone can explain the exact difference between a game engine and the actual game.

Comment: I removed the part where you ask if you should build your own engine or just make the game: this kind of question is too broad for this site as it really depends on what you intend to do.

Comment: A game engine is the canvas, paint, brushes, etc. The game is the art you create using those tools on that medium.

Comment: It is worth researching about the history of game engines. They didn't always have editors and such. In fact, many of the early game engines were were created as part of games and then later isolated to be able to reuse them in other games.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a game engine is more of a tool you use to create a game. It's something like Unity3D or Unreal, etc. But the difference of creating a game (I'll try to come up with the best explanation I can!) is that the game engine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine) already supplies the bare bones you need to create a game, and most times, a lot of extra stuff also. The physics, editor, scene editors, etc, are stuff that a game engine would most likely have. Now, if you were to create 3D a game ALL BY YOURSELF, you would most likely want to use a rendering engine like OpenGL or DirectX. Like Minecraft used code written in Java, and there was no game engine used to create it. But there was a rendering engine to render all the 3D graphics.

Comment: I recommend removing your opinion about Unity. Not that you're much wrong, it's just that it doesn't fit the question.